# PyCharm reformat code does not wrap line to specified length

Tags: python, pycharm, word-wrap

When I highlight a section of python code in PyCharm 2020.3 Community Edition and attempt a reformat code operation, the reformatted code does not respect the 80 character limit I (believe that I) specified in the settings.

What am I doing wrong?

My settings are as shown below:

[image]

For example, I would like the 86 character line:

```
        normalized_stop_band_edge: float = prms['stop_band_edge_in_hz'] * sam_int_in_s
```

to be reformatted to, e.g.,:

```
        normalized_stop_band_edge: float = prms['stop_band_edge_in_hz'] * \
                                           sam_int_in_s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line wrapping is language specific. In the question a screenshot of the general IDE setting is shown, but if working with a Python file the general editor setting is superseded by the language specific setting.

For the example code in the question to wrap for the line length limit using `Reformat Code` (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd>) 2 settings must be configured: At `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Code Style` `>` `Python` `>` `Wrapping and Braces`.

1. `Hard wrap at` (80).
2. `Ensure right margin is not exceeded`

[image]

But this is still not enough. It has to be considered the example in the question has 2 levels of indentation (8 whitespaces, or 2 tabs). This will require running `Reformat Code` (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd>) twice, and that the example line be in a scope that has 2 levels of indentation. So for example:

```py
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def my_func():

        normalized_stop_band_edge: float = prms['stop_band_edge_in_hz'] * sam_int_in_s
```

Initially:

[image]

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> once:

[image]

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> twice:

[image]